# Derivation of the dirac delta

Tags: calculus, derivatives, dirac-delta

I have the following function: $$\int^{a+\epsilon}_{a-\epsilon}f(x)\dfrac{1}{\epsilon} dx$$

When I take the limit $\epsilon \to 0$, I want to show that this becomes equivalent to the behavior of the Dirac delta function under the integral: $2\int_{a-\epsilon}^{a+\epsilon}f(x)\delta (x-a)dx=2f(a)$.

I apply the following:

$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int^{a+\epsilon}_{a-\epsilon}f(x)\dfrac{1}{\epsilon} dx = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \dfrac{\int^{a+\epsilon}_{a}f(x)dx}{\epsilon} + \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \dfrac{\int^{a}_{a-\epsilon}f(x)dx}{\epsilon}=2f(a)$$ by using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus twice.

Is this derivation correct? Sorry if it looks too trivial, I am little bit exhausted and can't be sure if I am doing it correctly.

Comment: Is $f$ continuous at $x = a$? If not, this won't work.

Comment: Yes, $f$ is continuous on its domain, and at $a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $f$ is continuous,

$$\min_{x \in [a -\epsilon,a]} f(x) \cdot \epsilon \leq \int_{a - \epsilon}^a f(x) \ dx \leq \max_{x \in[a -\epsilon,a]} f(x) \cdot \epsilon$$

Thus
$$\min_{x \in [a -\epsilon,a]} f(x)  \leq {1 \over \epsilon} \int_{a - \epsilon}^a f(x) \ dx \leq \max_{x \in[a -\epsilon,a]} f(x) $$

Similarly,
$$\min_{x \in [a ,a+\epsilon]} f(x)  \leq {1 \over \epsilon} \int_{a }^{a+ \epsilon} f(x) \ dx \leq \max_{x \in[a ,a+\epsilon]} f(x) $$

In both cases, as $\epsilon \to 0$, the max and min of $f(x)$ converge to $f(a)$, again by continuity of $f$

Hence

$$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \int_{a - \epsilon}^{a+ \epsilon} {f(x)\over\epsilon} \ dx = 2 f(a)$$

---

We can also rewrite this more simply without the splitting, noting that

$$\min_{x \in [a -\epsilon,a+\epsilon]} f(x) \cdot (2\epsilon) \leq \int_{a - \epsilon}^{a+\epsilon} f(x) \ dx \leq \max_{x \in[a -\epsilon,a+\epsilon]} f(x) \cdot (2\epsilon)$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is my Fundamental Theorem of Calculus is acceptable as well?

Comment: Yes, I should think so. It is conceptually more complicated, but only slightly.